# Is it a good idea to give a very short time for a decision of a professor job?

Tags: job-search, interview

I recently completed a final round interview for an AP job. I told the interview committee that I only have about a few days to respond to other offers and would appreciate if they could let me know the decision as soon as possible although I know that they are interviewing other candidates as well. Is it a good idea? The interview went really well.

Comment: What does A stand for? Associate, assistant, or adjunct?

Comment: It’s Assistant!

Answer (score 3):

Putting on prior conditions isn't going to help you as they have constraints. If their rules require interviewing n (say 3) candidates they need time to arrange that and probably don't have a way to make it work as quickly as you require.

Asking for a decision asap and stating that you have your own constraints might be ok (or not), but anything beyond that will likely hurt, not help. Even Einstein wasn't recognized for his brilliance in his earliest days.

You can't always force the world into the lane you would like. Make your decisions at the point you need to make them.

Asking others for a few extra days to decide is another alternative that is probably less likely to be a problem if you have an offer. ("Probably", not certainly)

Answer (score 2):

If this is in the United States, making a job offer will require multiple levels of approval.  You will not have a firm job offer in a few days.  If the committee thinks you are going to decline because you have accepted another offer, they will not offer you the job.  Communicate clearly if you are still seeking the job.

We cannot predict what they will do.